# martingale bounds.

Tags: probability-theory, martingales, probability-limit-theorems

If $(X_n)_n$ is an independent non-negative sequence, or r.v's with common mean 1. Then, I am trying to prove that

$$ P(\sup_n\prod_{I=1}^n X_i\ge \varepsilon)\le\frac{1}{\varepsilon}$$
for all $\varepsilon>0$. Since we have a mean of 1, we know that $Y_n=\prod_i X_i$ is a martingale and also has mean 1. however I am unsure of where to go from here.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doob%27s_martingale_inequality